# Nginx check running process on destination before forwarding traffic

Tags: nginx, linux-networking, load-balancing

I'm configuring Nginx as UDP load balancer between four servers with the following configurations:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen     7004 udp;
        #UDP traffic will be forwarded to the "server_list" upstream group
        proxy_pass server_list;
    proxy_responses 0;
    }
    server {
        listen     1813 udp;
        #UDP traffic will be forwarded to the "server_list_5g" upstream group
        proxy_pass server_list_5g;
    proxy_responses 0;
    }
    upstream  server_list {
    server 192.168.1.2:7004;
    server 192.168.1.3:7004;
    server 192.168.1.4:7004;
    server 192.168.1.5:7004;    
    }
    upstream  server_list_5g {
    server 192.168.1.2:1813;    
    server 192.168.1.3:1813;
    server 192.168.1.4:1813;
    server 192.168.1.5:1813;
    }
}
```

I want to check a specific process running on the destination before sending the traffic to avoid sending the traffic to a destination which will not handle it.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, with UDP, you can't use nginx's builtin health monitoring - or anything which relies on bi-directional flows without a knowledge of the protocol (and if the protocol will always make replies).

Nginx plus (i.e. the $$$ version) has the ngx_http_api_module which provides the capability of reconfiguring nginx (including backends) on the fly. If you're using the open-source version then you're going to have to work a bit harder. A quick google turned up [redx](https://github.com/rstudio/redx) which appears to provide the backend membership capability you need - but I can't comment as to its compatability/stability. There are probably other nginx solutions out there.

If I were presented with this as a task, I would be spending some time looking for what else is available other than nginx. While it is handy in a pinch, this is not really nginx core focus.